# Business Japanese: what's the proper way to say "please visit [this URL]"?

Tags: business-japanese, email

I'm writing a business e-mail to a Japanese speaking person, and I need to direct them to a certain URL. In English I would write "please visit http://www.example.com". I'm not sure the best way to say that in Japanese. My best guess is something like "http://www.example.comに訪ねてください", and if I was writing a friend I'd probably just try that figuring that they'd understand even if it wasn't quite right. But since this is formal business correspondence I want to make sure it's right.

Comment: @Kentaro Tomono - IIRC, my original intent when asking this question was to give instructions on how to change a user's profile on our website. So I was writing something like "To change your setting, go to www.example.com, then click "my profile", then click "settings".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26746/discussion-on-question-by-joshua-carmody-business-japanese-whats-the-proper-wa).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- `...に訪ねる` is ungrammatical. You have to use `...を訪ねる`.
- In the first place, using the expression 'visit' is metaphoric. It may work in English, but it is a bit strange in Japanese to use `訪ねる`. As cypher writes, `ご覧ください` 'please see' is more natural.

Comment: I would like personally ask who upvoted this after the questioner wrote the further details of **instruction**. If you were him, would you simply use 「…を御覧下さい」？The questioner has given the more detailed instruction, which I think requires additional comment in order for the users to **change their profiles.**  ***How would you react to the questioner's upgraded instruction***??? ***I would personally would like to know*** with thank you in advance. Kindly be noted I am saying **in terms of technical process**

Answer (score 7):

On the off chance that the information on the referred page is related to the contents of your email, I'll add in `～をご参照【さんしょう】ください` meaning "Please refer to..."

Answer (score 4):

As I commented at your comment line, it looks like personally to me Choko san might not submit her own answer, I would like to "answer" instead....

### Choko san's own answer ( about which I think it is quite appropriate )

> "To change your setting, go to www.example.com, then click "my profile", then click "settings" >> Well in that case I think you could say something like **「設定を変更するには、www.example.comを開いて / にアクセスして、"my profile"** → **"setting" の順にクリックしてください。**」

or

> 「**設定はwww.example.comから/よりご変更いただけます。/ 設定の変更はwww.example.comよりお願いします・から行ってください。"my profile"→"setting"の順にクリックしてください。**」etc

P.S I would like not to change her comment since I think it is not appropriate to change someone's **original** answer/comment without paying due heed to the person.

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Here, I would like to start my opinion....

**Regarding why to direct someone to a certain URL needs such a long speech.**

For example, this is the Yahoo! Japan's guidance.

> ★MyYahoo!では Yahoo! JAPANページを
>   　自分仕様にカスタマイズできます！
>
> ・ドラッグ＆ドロップで、自分が
>   　見やすい位置にコンテンツを移動
>   ・ヤフオクやメールなど、いつも
>   　使っているYahoo! JAPANサービス
>   　をまとめて表示
>   ・気になるサイトのRSSフィードを
>   　追加して一緒に表示
>
> ▼My Yahoo!の特徴はこちら
>   http://docs.my.yahoo.co.jp/newmyyahoo/promo/index.html

Translation

> You can customize your Yahoo! Japan's page as you like here at MyYahoo! ( page)
>
> Use the drag & drop function to place your favorite contents to your preferred place, ( to be continued )
>
> You can display your favorite contents such as Yahoo auction or Yahoo e-mail at your preferred place.
>
> You can display the RSS feeds of the sites of your own choice in addition to the above.
>
> For the above peculiar My Yahoo! services, click 
>    http://docs.my.yahoo.co.jp/newmyyahoo/promo/index.html

Granted, since I have not seen your PC's screen? to users, I can not say perfectly, but **should there be explanations of your direction to users on your screen, explaining the features or services or setting ups as I presented above as an example ( = My Yahoo )**, then I think what you need to direct the users to the site is just to direct them to "click" as below.

> こちらをクリックして下さい。 ( Please click here )

like Choko-san's answer.

### If I were you, ( my personal way )

I may probably would like to do like this ( almost same with that of Choko-san )

> 貴殿（きでん）のプロフィールを変更されたい場合はまずこちらをクリックして下さい。
>   　http://www.example.com

Translation

> If you would like to change your profile kindly click below first.
>   http://www.example.com

Then I would probably change the further instruction according to which site ( at the main screen or the at the above link ) the explanation about the later "Profile" and "Setting" link is.

No1. In a case that the explanation about the link to "Profile" and "Settings" is **not** at http://www.example.com

> リンク先に「プロフィール」という項目が有ります。まずそこをクリックして下さい。
>   　その中に「セッティング」という項目が有りますのでそこをクリックして貴殿の
>   　プロフィールを変更して下さい。

Translation

> After you click the above link, there is an additional link 「My profile」.
>   Please click it. Inside the page ( link ) you can find a link 「Settings」. Kindly click it and change your profile as your prefer to.

No2. In a case that the further instruction **is at** the http://www.example.com. ( = meaning, after the users click http://www.example.com )

> 「プロフィール」の項目をクリックして下さい。

Translation

> Kindly click 「Profile」.

Then after the users click the "Profile" link, I would probably add,

> 「セッティング」をクリックして下さい。そこで貴殿のプロフィールの変更が出来ます。

Translation

> Kindly click 「Settings」. You can change your profile as you like there.

So No2 is kind of a **step by step** explanation.

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

P.S Since I have no way but to imagine in my way your "main screen" or the related links, I just wrote imagining at my own discretion.

Have a nice day and thank you.

Comment: is `www.example.comを開いて` あいて or ひらいて?